# Não consigo exibir nada em uma view JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, view

Estou mexendo em uma aplicação web para desenvolver um módulo, mas não consigo exibir nada na view, nem mesmo uma mensagem simples.

A view carrega o template, mas não exibe nada que eu coloque na view. A unica coisa que tá sendo exibida é o título na aba do navegador, através da tag `<ui:define>`.
Segue abaixo o código:

**View**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
            template="template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="titulo">
        Ver Livros de Ordem
    </ui:define>

    <h:outputText value="#{verLivrosOrdemController.msg}" />

</ui:composition>
```

**Managed Bean**

```java
package br.org.aplicacao.servicosOnline.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class VerLivrosOrdemController implements Serializable {
    String msg;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg() {
        this.msg = "Em breve!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não colocou o código do seu template.

Se você não definiu, você deverá definir um corpo do seu template para poder exibi-lo.

Igual você fez com o seu título. Exemplo:

```
<ui:composition ... template="template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="titulo">
        Ver Livros de Ordem
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <h:outputText value="#{verLivrosOrdemController.msg}" />
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Seu template deverá ser algo assim:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

  <h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.0 - Exemplo de template</title>
  </h:head>

  <h:body>

    <ui:insert name="titulo">
        <h1>Título da minha pagina</h1>
    </ui:insert>

    <ui:insert name="conteudo">
        Informações do conteúdo
    </ui:insert>

    <ui:insert name="rodape">
        Informações do rodapé
    </ui:insert>

  </h:body>

</html>
```

---

#### Referência:

- http://www.universidadejava.com.br/materiais/jsf-template/

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Obrigada!